# Java DES decryption exception in first try

Tags: java, android, encryption, des, spongycastle

In my project, secure communication is used between android client and server so all messages between them are encrypted as DES algorithm.
I have used default Java Provider and also SpongyCastle but in first try of decryption, it gives the below exception.

```
javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: last block incomplete in decryption
at org.spongycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BaseBlockCipher.engineDoFinal(BaseBlockCipher.java:815)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:1111)
```

Encoded String below

```
SB1DbM9MbtFYY62OtDwkU4+CxlHi7wj9MQIPVMsoktVyPZDoi79V2Hx5pzjLgQvxXKJSLP7BpNYZg4hlbVGzkCE8x4LTmTbdQzwweMjlOGfTbZSNA+iL1sx0ctRYFIVLu7c0ZnsSnJ4Fq2tdL2XS3YQW3/MokoAlyFK6lhBf/4t+VpZ/cy+s9g==
```

In the second try, it successfully decrypts String. I couldn't find the problem.

Source Code that Encrypt and Decrypt

```
private Cipher encryptCipher = null;
private Cipher decryptCipher = null;

static {
    Security.insertProviderAt(new org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider(), 1);
}

public void initialize(SecretKey key) throws Exception {
    try {
        encryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding", "SC");
        decryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding", "SC");
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    encryptCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    decryptCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
}

public String encryptBase64(String unencryptedString) throws Exception {
    byte[] unencryptedByteArray = unencryptedString.getBytes("UTF-8");
    byte[] encryptedBytes = encryptCipher.doFinal(unencryptedByteArray);
    return new String(Base64.encodeBase64(encryptedBytes), "UTF-8");
}

public String decryptBase64(String encryptedString) throws Exception {
    try {
        byte[] unencryptedByteArray = decryptCipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(encryptedString.getBytes("UTF-8")));
        String message = new String(unencryptedByteArray, "UTF-8");
        return message;
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: I would guess it is something technical and simple that is causing the problem and it has nothing to do with the encryption itself. Put more technical details (code maybe) about what you do and how and maybe we can help find the problem.

Comment: Thanks @selalerer. I have put source code.